# Cant build delphi package dclP4DEnvironmentProject.bpl for PythonEnvironments (P4D)

Tags: python, delphi, rad-studio, python4delphi

I'm trying to use the delphi4python library, as well as the PythonEnvironments ﻿library:
https://github.com/Embarcadero/PythonEnvironments
https://github.com/Embarcadero/python4delphi

I have installed P4D successfully, for both 32bit and 64bit. However when trying to install PythonEnvironments, I face a issue for the design time package dclP4DEnvironmentProject.bpl.

I get the following error message when attempting to build or install it:

> [Exec Error] EXEC(1): Invalid syntax. [Exec Error] The command
> "..\reg_env.bat 22.0 "K:\PythonEnvi\PythonEnvironments\packages.." "
> exited with code 1.

This is followed up by a error dialog:

> Cannot open file "K:\PythonEnvi\PythonEnvironments\packages\EXEC". The system cannot
> find the file specified.

I have looked inside the packages folder, and do not see a folder or file named EXEC. the closest thing I found is a folder named ExecCmd, which is at the path:

> PythonEnvironments\src\Tools\ExecCmd

I have my suspicion maybe its something to do with the reg_env.bat file, however I'm not sure what to do regarding it. Your guidance in this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after trying many things, I have solved the problem. when building PythonEnvironments, open the P4DPythonEnvironmentsComponentSuite.groupproj

for 32bit build in this order:

1. P4DTools.BPL
2. P4DEnvironment.BPL
3. dclP4DEnvironment.BPL

Press 'install' on dclP4DEnvironment.BPL, which will also install dclP4DEnvironmentProject.bpl by itself. Everything seems to work fine for now.